# Construct a 64 bit mask register from four 16 bit ones

Tags: x86-64, simd, avx512

What is the best way to end up with a `__mmask64` from four `__mmask16`? I just want to concatenate them. Can't seem to find a solution on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AVX-512 has hardware instructions for concatenating two mask registers, for example 2x [`kunpckwd` instructions](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/kunpckbw:kunpckwd:kunpckdq) and one `kunpckdq` would do the trick here.

(Each instruction is 4 cycle latency, port 5 only, on SKX and Ice Lake.  https://uops.info.  But at least the 2 independent ones in the first step can mostly overlap, starting one cycle apart, limited by competition for port 5.  But they won't all be ready at once anyway, if the compiler schedules the instructions that generate the 4 masks so one pair should be ready first so it can get started.)

```
// compiles nicely with GCC/clang/ICC.  Current MSVC has major pessimizations
inline
__mmask64 set_mask64_kunpck(__mmask16 m0, __mmask16 m1, __mmask16 m2, __mmask16 m3)
{
    __mmask32 md0 = _mm512_kunpackw(m1, m0);  // hi, lo
    __mmask32 md1 = _mm512_kunpackw(m3, m2);
    __mmask64 mq = _mm512_kunpackd(md1, md0);
    return mq;
}
```

That's your best bet if your `__mask16` values are actually in `k` registers, where a compiler will have them if they're the result of AVX-512 compare/test intrinsics like `_mm512_cmple_epu32_mask`.  If they're coming from an array you generated earlier, it might be better to combine them with plain scalar stuff (See Paul's answer), instead of slowly getting them into mask registers with `kmov`.  `kmov k, mem` is 3 uops for the front-end, with scalar integer load and a `kmov k, reg` back-end uops, plus an extra front-end uop for no apparent reason.

---

`__mmask16` is just a typedef for `unsigned short` (in gcc/clang/ICC/MSVC) so you *can* simply manipulate it like an integer, and compilers will use `kmov` as necessary.  (This can lead to pretty inefficient code if you're not careful, and unfortunately current compilers aren't smart enough to compile a shift/OR function into using `kunpckwd`.)

There *are* intrinsics like `unsigned int _cvtmask16_u32 (__mmask16 a)` but they're optional for current compilers that implement `__mmask16` as `unsigned short`.

---

To look at compiler output for a case where `__mmask16` values start out in `k` registers, it's necessary to write a test function that uses intrinsics to create the mask values.  (Or use inline asm constraints.)  The standard x86-64 calling conventions handle `__mmask16` as a scalar integer, so as a function arg it's already in an integer register, not a `k` register.

```
__mmask64 test(__m256i v0, __m256i v1, __m256i v2, __m256i v3)
{
    __mmask16 m0 = _mm256_movepi16_mask(v0);  // clang can optimize _mm_movepi8_mask into pmovmskb eax, xmm avoiding k regs
    __mmask16 m1 = _mm256_movepi16_mask(v1);
    __mmask16 m2 = _mm256_movepi16_mask(v2);
    __mmask16 m3 = _mm256_movepi16_mask(v3);

    //return set_mask64_mmx(m0,m1,m2,m3);
    //return set_mask64_scalar(m0,m1,m2,m3);
    return set_mask64_kunpck(m0,m1,m2,m3);
}
```

With GCC and clang, that compiles to (**[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrWVX0AGTy1MAOWcARpjEIADMAOykAA6oQoTmtHaOLsoxcWZ0Xj7%2BTkEhEUaYJhm0DATMxARJzq6chcUJZRUEWX6BwSDakULlldUpdT3NrTl5neEAlEaoDsTIHFI6od7IjlgA1JqhNnhOTt4ExN4AdAhb2JoyAIKXN9rLVFhU6wD6LwCy7wAab7dve8whABrABs3HWIgILycgNB3GhTnEEH%2BMOBnBB6ycMlIrwRsPRmLquIBaIxTm0OJR%2BLJoQmt004X013WLPWxEwBFmtHWyLxwLBEwRL0hLyieHRECxOKcRPJ0tpWyZN3CABF6fd3HgqPTrlT%2BeCRai4cKWKpiLySUCCVLiUbrUS9VayRTbdTMQrrgylay2RyuTyoI6BViJpttlsbOsZHTmT6fQzI1ALUbg5xQxGI%2Bt0TGrnH4%2BFE4G%2BXCJuT0%2BHtutQtoc3nWQmA8nYcHaWGbJnuAAOOmhJUMtWe3XFsEQjnQ5vwoEOWhRZBApukzHY12LmWU4vWl2O60e5Xe1mO6uY9AyMMq157ACsnG0LynM%2BYc4A7pLZdHFbcfYftMfOGeL04163veUSPkCL5OKE0o1h%2BsYskG4JOAAjv%2BCJAXe06gXO6CSugsonj2%2B4suynLENyyGwcqA43IOVwIesBCYD0FraJeIJ4OsABuy7/Kx7FcQ60J8RxnFbkJbEibuXqfgeG5kqeWzngifHQqgnGYGK6LjsCEDcYRLIAPQGesqxqMAJlqOsqBRGY%2BwAF6YABqnqWKnbaUC6wHKg6xRE4alOMCATrJgzDiDi4h7OszCcageD4Oo6weeywBCDJ8FyYSqF7CpfkueKILubpaaUV%2BGXkll5Jsc5Gn5YVomEWlK5Ou6FU5WpNVaUaukKr2jVGSR/qGhOCJIlKa5ypBDVwes/V%2BmRo5Qim8JCKaFSSti40UpNJWsgN81DfqGEznO62kJtZ09X2qq3FIUysNIl7yK4sjyKg0jtnoBgQjMcyOUsnDyAQ0hyBMUxAmEnbHOEIIRJeMggpe3DhAAnKEMidpeKjSNwT3A690jyEIIDYkDL1THAsAwFAVMQEgaBOGK7BkBQED04zHSmeoN4yNiVB4KwjHEETEABHjpABN4FQAJ7SADpD004VgEAA8rQrAyy9pBYDC6jsGL%2BDsqYeDqUTmuYOImDIA4jGy/IBxFGLrB4AExDS3YWBi4cuy21M/CMKaHA8HwdAEMIYiSJrSh1Ko6goAYBgqM7ROQFM1klKbAC0yuhOsGcwnMZyhCqwJS6oQKYBn0XiEBhNFJbJSWNY/S1KQ7gjO0IR1Gk8R0M3qSxD3tDt7kHSDHXRt0E0fT2DUyjGPXjS9C03htCPndGEvfeDEvw9jGm0yzPMXB3Q9uOa29UjiJ2IIZyOnPmTexwyE/PK4IQJCbPcRJ2Az/PBJ/oQ0zrA%2BvoPQgM8ag1IODOGWMpA4zOiAS8l5jjcE4IjGQl5AHcG4MjcIQdnpyFIBfQmxNSCkxBqQCmiAUCoF/kzcglA2Z/xCMATgbC%2BD80FsLUWmsJa0GlrbeWtDFb0FVurfWmAdbAD1prA2C8TZi3Npba2Cw5b23uprJ2Ls3YYAWIQr2TgfbB3oEwNggdeB%2BzDhIMWSgKQxw0PHPQicAjJwgKnGyCRM7Z1zvnZAhdi5AlLswculdOLVxvLXBoFgIDuC3hSNuK9RgdC7NEAeJQ4mpPSAkXeyTOz1AXpPTeM8Bj5InqUHeiSO5hGRhvZoW9amVByfkZGUwhA/SPvvDRj1SAEPxpfa%2Bt9wTAGQMgLMnBjh/ggG/IgxAAHf1oezWZSwazAMcbocBZMpgIBClgEIbioGIOxBo%2BBvSiEEyMKQ8ht0T5SG0PIQxYJjiXk7DeQBMgUZ4PCNwTGpziFkIgZQmmdMFnMIYazEFTMQCcWQFEKILxOKcGRi8bQSKABqDAtKcBkC8cQYIOEC2CNwsWfCBFSDlgrJWYiNaEO1mZGRNK8CGzMAos2FsrY2zJXbegDtNHO1dsQKW7s9GAyOIYzlvsQ6mL1kHSxIhrGRzCCoMycdPpOK0a49x6dpBZx/JXAuIArioq%2BEBXOABxTikSCmuBiU3YpLcEnZCqV3NJCR6ndxKE0ue48ShTyqHar1UTynDEqWvOeRTkgtyGI0kNe9WntMDjc7pvzpC4sQkIaFAlkbHBResdF6IJmnimfgGZcycQ/0WQA1sICDAbJBlsnZHR9nHPuWEZBqDOzQ07MjbQMhtCdlYrwZNUgSEkwgWDEAIJxn3BBNoHBoRvk9pBMjNBsDQhn0IX8q5kCNF3J6WLTdY7SDqSFgkEA3AgA%3D)**):

```
# gcc 11.1  -O3 -march=skylake-avx512
test(long long __vector(4), long long __vector(4), long long __vector(4), long long __vector(4)):
        vpmovw2m        k3, ymm0
        vpmovw2m        k1, ymm1
        vpmovw2m        k2, ymm2
        vpmovw2m        k0, ymm3     # create masks

        kunpckwd        k1, k1, k3
        kunpckwd        k0, k0, k2
        kunpckdq        k4, k0, k1   # combine masks

        kmovq   rax, k4              # use mask, in this case by returning as integer
        ret
```

I could have used the final mask result for a blend intrinsic between two of the inputs, for example, but the compiler didn't try to avoid `kunpck` by doing 4x `kmov` (also only 1 port).

MSVC 19.29 -O2 -Gv -arch:AVX512 does a rather poor job, extracting each mask to a scalar integer regs between intrinsics.  like

```
MSVC 19.29
        kmovw   ax, k1
        movzx   edx, ax
        ...
        kmovd   k3, edx
```

This is supremely dumb, not even using `kmovw eax, k1` to zero-extend into a 32-bit register, not to mention not realizing that the next `kunpck` only cares about the low part of its input anyway, so there was not need to kmov the data to/from an integer register at all.   Later, it even uses this, apparently not realizing that `kmovd` writing a 32-bit register zero-extends into the 64-bit register.  (To be fair, GCC has some dumb missed optimizations like that around its `__builtin_popcount` intrinsic.)

```
; MSVC 19.29
        kmovd   ecx, k2
        mov     ecx, ecx
        kmovq   k1, rcx
```

The `kunpck` intrinsics do have strange prototypes, with inputs as wide as their outputs, e.g.

```
__mmask32 _mm512_kunpackw (__mmask32 a, __mmask32 b)
```

So perhaps this is tricking MSVC into manually doing the `uint16_t` -> `uint32_t` conversion by going to scalar and back, since it apparently doesn't know that `vpmovw2m  k3, ymm0` already zero-extends into the full `k3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just treat `__mmask16` and `__mmask64` like 16 bit and 64 bit ints, e.g.

```c
__mmask64 set_mask64(__mmask16 m0, __mmask16 m1, __mmask16 m2, __mmask16 m3)
{
    return (((__mmask64)m0) << 0)
         | (((__mmask64)m1) << 16)
         | (((__mmask64)m2) << 32)
         | (((__mmask64)m3) << 48);
}
```

or perhaps:

```c
__mmask64 set_mask64(__mmask16 m0, __mmask16 m1, __mmask16 m2, __mmask16 m3)
{
    return (__mmask64)_mm_set_pi16(m0, m1, m2, m3);
}
```

Both of the above use scalar/SSE code. Using AVX512 mask intrinsics will be more efficient (see [@Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68322930/253056) for better solutions).

Comment: Note that the code-gen is pure scalar integer because `__mask16` is actually just a typedef for `unsigned short`.  To actually make the compiler deal with values in `k` registers, you'd want to give it inputs that come from vector->mask intrinsics, and maybe use the result as a mask for some instruction, maybe just mask->vector `vpmovm2d`

Comment: Also, `_mm_set_pi16` is an MMX intrinsic, although your cast from `__m64` to `__mmask64` does work with GCC and clang without even a warning.  Although clang does use `vpinsrw` into an XMM reg, eventually using `vmovq rax, xmm0`.  Apparently x64 MSVC doesn't recognize that intrinsic at all (probably because MS decided for some reason to remove compiler support for MMX in 64-bit code.)  And with 32-bit MSVC, it doesn't know how to do the conversion: https://godbolt.org/z/48cTxeKdE

Comment: (Added an answer using `_mm512_kunpackw` and `_mm512_kunpackd`)